# Can't export data from a spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I parsed 500k tweets as a test using spark NLP. The dataframe looks fine. I converted the arrays to  a string. Using

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def array_to_string(my_list):
    return '[' + ','.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list]) + ']'

array_to_string_udf = udf(array_to_string, StringType())

result = result.withColumn('token', array_to_string_udf(result["token"])).withColumn('ner', array_to_string_udf(result["ner"])).withColumn('embeddings', array_to_string_udf(result["embeddings"])).withColumn('ner_chunk', array_to_string_udf(result["ner_chunk"])).withColumn('document', array_to_string_udf(result["document"]))
```

The dataframe looks fine. However, whenever I try to convert it to pandas, export it to a csv I keep getting the following error

```
PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 584, in main
  File "C:\spark\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 562, in read_int
    length = stream.read(4)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Which makes me think spark is not talking to python. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

When calling [toPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html)

> all the data is loaded into the driver’s memory

The effect of calling `toPandas` is basically the same as when calling [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html?highlight=collect#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect).

A better approach to write the contents of a dataframe into a csv would be to use PySpark's [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html) directly:

```python
result.write.csv('my_result.csv')
```

*Edit*: probably not directly related to the question, but it would be possible to replace the udf with native Spark functions ([lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html), [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html) and [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws.html)):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result.withColumn("token", F.concat(F.lit("["), F.concat_ws(",", "token"),F.lit("]")))....
```

Replacing the udf with Spark functions will increase the performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the cited error comes up regardless of wether I try to export to a csv or call the toPandas function

Comment: @ViktorAvdulov could you please try to limit the amount of data using [limit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit.html)? Does `result.limit(100).write.csv('my_result.csv')` return the same error?